# how to take and skip records using TSQL instead of linq

Tags: linq, t-sql

I want to take le's say ten records but skip the first 20? I know how to do that in linq, but how to do it in TSqL.

In linq would be something like this:

```
qp = dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Active).OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                .Skip((curPage - 1) * prodPerPage).Take(prodPerPage);
```

Comment: Edit the question add sample data & desired result would helpful .

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (and most other databases), `ROW_NUMBER` offers a general way to do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_column) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN 21 AND 30; -- skip the first 20 records, and keep the 10 after that
```